# Bad HTML using SmtpClient to send MailMessage

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.0, html-email

I am using System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient.Send() to send a System.Net.Mail.MailMessage object. The MailMessage object has the IsBodyHtml Property set to true. I have the following settings in my App.config file:

```
<system.net>
  <mailSettings>
    <smtp deliveryMethod="SpecifiedPickupDirectory" >
      <specifiedPickupDirectory pickupDirectoryLocation="C:\Pickup"/>
    </smtp>
  </mailSettings>
</system.net>
```

Some of the HTML in the email body is not being converted properly when the EML file is being generated. For example:

```
<img style="width:120px;height:160px;padding-left:2px;" src="http://images.mysite.com/image280.jpg" />
```

Becomes...

```
<img style=3D=
"width:120px;height:160px;padding-left:2px;" src=3D"http://images=
..mysite.com/image280.jpg" />
```

Notice the extra period before mysite.com in the src attribute. This is causing the image link to be broken and not display.  It appears to be a bug with how lines are broken up in EML format. I cannot find any documentation online about it.

EDIT:
I've noticed this happens everytime a line needs to break at a '.' (period) character. It puts two periods on the next line instead of one.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14465834/outlook-express-saving-eml-file-with-at-end-of-line) seems relevant but not sure if it will solve my problem.  Do I need to change the `Content-Transfer-Encoding` property in my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I fixed my problem referring to the answer of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6602318/system-net-mail-creating-invalid-emails-and-eml-files-inserting-extra-dots-in-h). I simply set the BodyEncoding property of the `MailMessage` object to `System.Text.Encoding.UTF8`